# API for creating directory in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to create directory in azure ad using api, does any such api is supported by azure? If yes then please share the api.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware of, there is no API for creating Azure AD tenants.
The documentation never mentions any: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-create-new-tenant